# Error while Encrypting using Jmeter for Response Value

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am currently working in a application where RSA Encryption is being used for Encrypting sensitive data. I have tried incorporating the standard encryption method but it is throwing errors. Can someone throw light on whether i am doing it right?

Below is the code i used in order to encrypt the value (string2Encrypt)

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

def publicKey = '5dy47yt7ty5ad283c0c4955f53csa24wse244wfrfafa34239rsgd89gfsg8342r93r98efae89fdf9983r9gjsdgnsgjkwt23r923r2r0943tf9sdg9d8gfsgf90sgsf89grw098tg09s90ig90g90s903r5244r517823rea8f8werf9842tf24tf42e0132saf9fg6f65afa43f12r103tf4040ryrw0e9rtqtwe0r9t04ty8842t03e9asfads0fgadg675'

def x509PublicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.decodeBase64())
def keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance('RSA')
defFactory.generatePublicc(x509PublicKey)
def string2Encrypt = '("testinga@gmail.com|testingb@gmail.com").'
def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA')encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE key)
def secretMessage = string2Encrypt.getBytes('UTF-8')
def encryptedMessage = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessage)

def encodedMessage = encryptedMessage.encodedBase64().toString()
vars.put('encodedMessage',encodedMessage)
```

The Error i am getting

```
javax.script.scriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertException: No Such Property: `defFactory for class: Script21`
```

The Output i expect to see once the passed parameters are encrypted

```
"ParameterEmailDetails":"428f8wefg87hg8s74tr52493r5219r0921tf09gv09sg0958t347tr1348r8feqacadvf98bnvncsaopdpwoq8r3r234r89r024rtf90eopfgsodg9503y68yhhi898jngdhhs9hg538hfhlhko539gh35l35s09fhbs09ns9htwj986jh3509h3250bsf90hsf9nsf0h9sf9h0"
```

Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You made a error while trying to copy-paste the code from some source, what you show is is not a valid Groovy code hence you're getting interpretation/compilation failures

This line:

```
defFactory.generatePublicc(x509PublicKey)
```

should look like

```
def key = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509PublicKey)
```

also this line:

```
def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA')encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE key)
```

should be either split into 2 lines:

```
def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA')
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
```

or put a semicolon between statements:

```
def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA');encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE key)
```

More information:

- [RSA in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-rsa)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As mentioned, i made the changes to my code and i am getting the below error now

"javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No Such Property: x509PublicKey for class: Script5"

Comment: it seems you've lost this line `def x509PublicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.decodeBase64())` during copying and pasting. You need to learn how [clipboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6) works